# RegEx match 7 to 11 digits with or without prefix

Tags: regex, validation

Hi I need a regex that will match a min of 7 digits to a max of 11 digits with an optional prefix of ptno or PTNO

I currently have...

```
^[pP]?[tT]?[nN]?[oO]?[0-9]+$
```

But this matches any number of digits... How do I restrict to min 7 or max 11 digits.

The following show valid and invalid combinations

```
PTNO01234567891     (valid max no of digits) 
12345678901         (valid max no of digits) 
PTNO9876543         (valid min no of digits) 
1234567             (valid min no of digits) 
PTNO000012345678    (invalid too many digits) 
012345678912        (invalid too many digits) 
PTNO098765          (invalid too few digits) 
123456          (invalid too few digits)
```

Actually I would be happy to have a regex that will take a value disregard optional prefix and any padded 0 and from what is left make sure I have a min of 7 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
^(ptno|PTNO)?\d{7,11}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VXIPpjssN7qjWc0w)

I am not sure about your meaning of *"prefix of ptno or PTNO"*. In your example you are allowing skipping of single letters here (**PNO** would match). I did a complete match of this prefix.

Comment: Thanks... Your's is more correct as you say I would not want PNO to match... Had already accepted @Sabuj Hassan's answer but am now using your answer. I think my original question confused matters a little.

Comment: To slow. Life is so hard ;).

Comment: @Mych You can still change your mind, there's no harm in swapping an accepted answer if that's the better answer. And if the case doesn't matter, you can use an ignorecase option (depends on the language/regex engine for its use).

Comment: @Jerry: I was glad to help. I am still no point hunter. But maybe time changes everything ;).

Comment: @wumpz Well, thing is, SO's goal is partly to help people who ask questions, but the main goal is to make it like a database of question/answers so that if someone has a question, they can search here and get the answer they need. Accepted answers are the ones that top the pool of answers and that's what people usually try first. I for one, wouldn't want to try a wrong solution thinking it's correct before looking for more solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `+` sign int `{7,11}` from your regex. `+` means one or more, that's why it is matching any amount of digits having more than 1:

```
^[pP]?[tT]?[nN]?[oO]?[0-9]{7,11}$
```

Comment: Thanks... and so quick... have to wait 10 mins to accept.

Answer (score 0):

What about using case-insensitive flag with the following:

```
^(?:ptno)?0*\d{7,}$
```

And if it should *only* be ptno *or* PTNO:

```
^(?:ptno|PTNO)?0*\d{7,}$
```

Comment: what about the maximum number of digits ?

Comment: Looks good but did not patch on my first example and made a match on my 6th example which it should not have.

Comment: I was following the last part: "Actually I would be happy to have a regex that will take a value disregard optional prefix and any padded 0 and from what is left make sure I have a min of 7 digits." No need to down-vote if you don't read the entire question.